# Android - Stuck in fetching Data of Current week from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an android application in which I would like to fetch the data from Monday of current week to Monday of next week.

I have tried the following query for doing the same in `MySQL` and it worked fine

```
select distinct  wr.report_id, wr.scheduled_time,wr.scheduled_hour, wr.status, wr.emp_id, wr.issue where wr.scheduled_time >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY) and wr.scheduled_time <  DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW())-8 DAY) and wr.status= 'Scheduled' order by wr.scheduled_time ASC
```

But I have tried to rewrite the same query for `SQLite` as mentioned below .But it is not working.

```
select distinct  wr.report_id, wr.scheduled_time,wr.scheduled_hour, wr.status, wr.emp_id, wr.issue where wr.scheduled_time >= datetime('now',(cast(strftime('%w', 'now') as integer)))
                        and wr.scheduled_time <  datetime('now', (cast(strftime('%w', 'now') as integer))-8 )
```

Please help me finding the solution.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).